# Unable to get child of nav element

Tags: html, css, children

I am having some trouble getting the child of  element. Here is the HTML code I have:

```
<div class="collasped-nav">
   <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
   <nav class="closed">
      <a href="#">Electronics</a>
      <a href="#">Kids & Baby</a>
   </nav>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.collasped-nav > i{
  color: #23527c;
}
.collasped-nav > nav{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.collasped-nav > nav.closed{
  display: none;
}
.collapsed-nav > nav > a{
  background-color: #23527c;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

For some reason, the follow `.collapsed-nav > nav > a` does not go into effect. Everything up to the `collapsed-nav > nav.closed` works, but the `collapsed-nav > nav > a` does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove display none and see

Comment: You have `display: none` on `li` element and you're wondering why it's not being shown? You told the browser not to show it!

Comment: typing error.. nothing else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's typo, use this:

```
.collasped-nav> nav> a{
  background-color: #23527c;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**Note:** Use have used `.collapsed-nav` but it should be `.collasped-nav`

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngj0jxz7/)

Comment: Thank you. I feel so stupid. It is quite late and I am not seeing things too clearly. Again thank you, I thought I was going crazy there for a second.

Answer (score 0):

> your class name is "**.collasped-nav**" but you using "**.collapsed-nav**"